# Обработка ошибок lua c++

Tags: c++, lua

Как можно реализовать вывод ошибки lua например: "Syntax error in script.lua 4 line". Использую LuaBridge и lua5.3. Вот мой класс который запускает луа скрипт:

```
//.h
#pragma once

#pragma comment(lib, "lua53.lib")
extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "lualib.h"
}

#include <iostream>
#include <LuaBridge/LuaBridge.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace luabridge;
class Lua_sup
{
private:

    string m_name;
    lua_State* L ;
    bool init_state = false;


public:
    Lua_sup(string name);
    Lua_sup() {};
    ~Lua_sup();
    void init();
    void test();
    bool get_state() { return init_state; }
};



//.cpp
 #include "Lua_sup.h"


void printMessage(const std::string& s) {
    cout << "print = " << s << endl;
}

string get_string() {
    return "Hi ";
}
Lua_sup::Lua_sup(string name)
{
    m_name = name;
    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
}


Lua_sup::~Lua_sup()
{


    lua_close(L);
}

void Lua_sup::init()
{
    //L = luaL_newstate();

    getGlobalNamespace(L).addFunction("printMessage", printMessage);
    int temp = luaL_loadfile(L, m_name.c_str()) || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
    if (temp)    {

        cout << "Error";

        init_state = false;
    }

    getGlobalNamespace(L).addFunction("get_string", get_string);
    getGlobalNamespace(L).addFunction("printMessage", printMessage);
    //int temp = lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
    init_state = true;
}


void Lua_sup::test()
{
    LuaRef hello_world_sum = getGlobal(L, "hello_world_sum");
    LuaRef plot = getGlobal(L, "plot");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int result = hello_world_sum(1, 2);
        cout << "Result = " << result << endl;


    }


    int result = hello_world_sum(1, 2);
    cout << "Result = " << result << endl;

    getchar();
}


//main
#include "Lua_sup.h"
using namespace luabridge;



int main() {


    Lua_sup lua("script.lua");
    lua.init();
    lua.test();

    lua.test();
    Lua_sup lua1("123.lua");
    lua1.init();
    lua1.test();

    lua.test();





}
```

Comment: Вам необходимо использовать дебаг интерфейс `lua_Debug`

Comment: А есть хоть какой то смысль в этой мешанины С и C++?

Comment: Используйте [`sol2`](https://sol2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю мост, но в обычном Lua делал так

```
if(luaL_dofile(l,name)){MessageBox(hWnd,lua_tostring(l,-1),"error",0);exit(1);}
```

Текст с пояснением к ошибке кладется на стек.
Запускающая код функция возвращает 0, если в коде нет ошибок.